# How to have global currentUser variable in Controller for Express using Passportjs?

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, mean

I'm using the MEAN stack with passportjs for authentication. I know I can automatically pass currentUser to every view, through this code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    next();
});
```

However, I also would like to access currentUser throughout my controller, for certain database queries. For example, checking whether or not a user has liked a post, before sending the relevant information to the view. Is there a similarly easy way to access currentUser in all of my different routes/controller logic?

I know I can use `req.user` to get the user within the logic of a route. But ideally I don't have to do `var currentUser = req.user` at the top of each route's logic.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: So the current user should be available on req.user in each of your controller methods, so i guess the question is how are you thinking it could be easier?

Comment: @LukeGaskell Correct. I've successfully been able to get current user through req.user. But I'm curious if there's a way to save a global variable equal to current user, instead of typing var `currentUser = req.user;` at the top of each route's logic.